# Unit Testing Google Cloud Endpoints : How to use BaseDevAppServerTestConfig?

Tags: google-app-engine, unit-testing, google-cloud-endpoints

I have created a REST API using Google Cloud Endpoints and am trying to unit test it locally. [The Javadoc here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/localunittesting/javadoc/com/google/appengine/tools/development/testing/DevAppServerTestRunner) says to create a class extending `BaseDevAppServerTestConfig`, but I have no idea what values to pass to the methods `getSdkRoot()` `getAppDir()` and `getClasspath()`. I do not have the app engine sdk or the app server installed locally, but pulled in as plugins via maven. The documentation is virtually nonexistent. So does anyone have any knowledge of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Update and Workaround

After no response here and a futile day spent digging around in the source of Endpoints, I bit decided to use the third party library, rest-assured to do my integration testing.

Still, I would be glad in knowing of a way to do this using the Endpoints classes only.